# How to recursively match nested functions with regex?

Tags: regex

I have something like this:

```
DoA(DoB(DoC()));
```

I am trying to write regex that would return the following:

```
DoA(DoB(DoC()))
DoB(DoC())
DoC()
```

Number of nested functions is unknown.

I've tried to do something with (?R) but it's not working quiet right:

`[a-zA-Z]+\((?:[^()]|((?R)))*\)`

Comment: Regex is generally not the right tool for recursive tasks like this. If you're trying to generalize this to parse a programming language, have you considered using a parser?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
(?=\b([a-zA-Z]+(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tSs3za/1). You will need to extract Group 1 values.

*Details*:

- `(?=` - start of a positive lookahead (to enable overlapping matches that do not share the same start position)

  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `([a-zA-Z]+(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\)))` - Group 1:

    - `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more ASCII letters (use `\p{L}+` to match any Unicode letters)
    - `(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))` - Group 2: `(`, then one or more repetitions of any one or more chars other than `(` and `)` or Group 2 recursed, and then a `)` char
- `)` - end of the positive lookahead.

Comment: This will happily also match the following input `DoA(DoB(DoC())a)`

Comment: And it will also ignore the parts where the parentheses are not balanced. ie it will partly match something like `DoA(((DoB(DoC()))`

Comment: I'm not saying that's wrong per se (OP has to decide whether that's acceptable or not). But from a theoretical CS point of view, you can't parse inputs like that with a regular expressions, but you would need a context free grammar for that.

Comment: what does ++ mean?

Comment: I would like to balance brackets as well, but I guess that's not possible?

Comment: I think this works somewhat '(?<!new\s)\b[a-zA-Z][^()\s]*\((?:((?R))|[^()])*\)' I could then manually recurse into matches and apply same pattern there

Comment: @Chebz 1) `++` one or more times, possessively, disallow backtracking into the pattern. 2) The brackets matched are balanced. 3) No idea why a pattern with `(?<!new\s)` can work with `DoA(DoB(DoC()));` string.

Comment: my bad I wanted to exclude constructor calls forgot to edit it out here

Comment: @Chebz If you need to adjust the pattern, please provide one or more test cases to explain what issue(s) you are still having. Best would be a code fiddle/demo at some site like ideone.com or tio.run.